# Is there a way to insert button to Superset UI?

Tags: apache-superset

I have requirement to solve.

I need to display a button that once pushed, it will run a curl command (i.e., a POST request to a remote endpoint).

Is it possible on Superset to insert on dashboard and how or I need to change source code to be displayed?

Comment: if you want answers, you need to formulate a proper question. Tell us what you have tried so far and try to be as specific as possible. The question you have asked is to broad, this is something you can research. But if you have found a way to integrate a button, then you can be more specific like " how can i adjust or integrate a rest api call into a button" ...